# Animating UserControl XAML

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, silverlight

I have been trying to animate the opening of a UserControl with no luck and was wondering if anyone could help?

I have a UserControl which simply holds information about a record. It opens up as a box on an existing page, however I would like the box to open with a simple animation. I'm trying to get the box to open with an expanding animation instead of the box just appearing.

Below is the code I have been working on.

```
<UserControl Name="RecordViewerUserControl" 
            xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk" 
            x:Class="VisionWare.MasterDataServices.Silverlight.UI.Common.RecordViewer"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
            xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls"
            xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:VisionWare.MasterDataServices.Silverlight.UI.Converters"
            xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
            mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            xmlns:vsm="clr-namespace:System.Windows;assembly=System.Windows"

            Height="490"
            Width="600"
            Margin="0,0,0,0">





<UserControl.Resources>
    <conv:DateConverter x:Key="dateConverter" />
    <conv:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="visibilityConverter" />
    <conv:EntityIdToUrlConverter x:Key="urlConverter"/>
    <conv:FileConverter x:Key="fileConverter"/>
    <conv:AlertImageURLConverter x:Key="alertConverter"/>

    <Style TargetType="UserControl" x:Key="CustomUserControlStyle">
        <Setter Property="Effect">
            <Setter.Value>
    <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RenderTransform).(Children)[0].ScaleX">
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.2" Value="1" />
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.25" Value="1.05" />
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.45" Value="0" />
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RenderTransform).(Children)[0].ScaleY">
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.2" Value="1" />
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.25" Value="1.05" />
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.45" Value="0" />
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </BeginStoryboard>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</UserControl.Resources>
```

I have changed my code according to @jrb 's advice...]

```
<UserControl.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UserControl.Loaded">
        <EventTrigger.Actions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RecordViewerUserControl" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" To="600"/>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RecordViewerUserControl" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" To="490"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger.Actions>
    </EventTrigger>
</UserControl.Triggers>
```

I have inserted this just after the initial UserControl opening tag.
It is not complaining anymore when the app is run, however it doesn't seem to be having an effect.

Any ideas? Am I missing something in the code behind?

Comment: Why not just use a `ChildWindow`? How do you open up this `UserControl` like a popup box?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. I'm not using a childWindow because I need to retain focus on the main window behind the userControl that pops up (you can still select records on the main UserControl is basically a pop up window.

Comment: What's the code that opens this usercontrol?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you test setting the size on the usercontrol to 1 then use event trigger loaded (i think) and a simple doubleanimation to increase the size of the control.

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
```

This is a working example, you can test it in kaxaml.

```
<Page
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     Width="1"
     Height="1"
     Background="Black">
     <Page.Triggers>
          <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
               <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                         <Storyboard>
                              <DoubleAnimation
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                                   To="200"/>
                              <DoubleAnimation
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
                                   To="200"/>
                         </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
               </EventTrigger.Actions>
          </EventTrigger>
     </Page.Triggers>
     <Grid>
     </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! It didn't seem to like the loaded routedEvent, but thank you. :)

Comment: Hi, thanks again for this. Can you point me in the right direction as to where to put this code? I can't seem to get it to work within the <UserControl.Resources> tags. I have also tried calling this code from the button event trigger itself when the window is opened.

Comment: Change page for usercontrol. You can also change the routedevent to something like mouse.click etc.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I think I may be getting somewhere now, thanks to your help! Although, do you know what other options I have for RoutedEvent? I can't seem to find many examples of this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think your animation values are wrong, in the end you should have a value of 1 (100% size) not 0.

Why do you animate on the first child of LayoutRoot? You should have `RecordViewerUserControl` as animation target instead.

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for your response! Sorry, I'm a beginner when it comes to XAML. I had put LayoutRoot because I was trying to target the whole content of the UserControl. When I animate on     RecordViewerUserControl it doesn't seem to animate at all?

Comment: put the style into a global place for testing. Also try setting the KeyTime of your frames to a higher value so you can see what happens.